# Add a section on rate limiting to the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, rate-limiting, help-center, question-restrictions

When I read the post ([assembly: what is the return value exactly doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055624/assembly-what-is-the-return-value-exactly-doing)), the user mentioned that he had hit a maximum number of posts.

I looked at the help page but didn't find anything. The help is also not searchable, it seems, because when I enter a search it looks only in the questions, so it's not context dependent on where the search is performed (might be a good thing to have it context aware).

I found many posts related to questions asking for limits of other properties like edits, tags, and so on. Wouldn't it be helpful if the help section contains a chapter where such limits are documented?

Comment: That's one of the things not highlighted anywhere, but still easily found here on Meta by searching.

Comment: I don't see why this should be a duplicate, because my question was not how big the limit is (or not primarily), rather it was more like why it is non intuitive how to find this limit.

Comment: @Devolus - But your title is asking for number of limit.

Comment: I fixed it. The posting is the whole, not just the title. ;)

Comment: @Devolus - Now ignore my close vote now. Side note: use [`@username`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/187824) to reply any specific user (as I did here). I didn't notice your comment.

Comment: There's an FAQ question about all rate-limiting here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Answer (score 3):

If you encounter any of the rate limits, you'll be shown an error message telling you which one.

Because the people most affected by the rate limits are already given the information they need directly in context, I don't think we need to make that information more prominent to the simply curious. As was already mentioned, there is a post here on MSO where users have collected info about the various rate limits, but most people don't need to know anything beyond the fact that most activities here are rate limited in some way.

---

**Edit:** The help center now has a search feature, so figuring out if your question is answered there should be much easier now.

I'm declining this feature request to include rate limiting in the help center, though, because the help center is *help*, not full documentation of every nitty gritty detail on the site. The information is available here on meta for people who want to dig for it, but if we got that granular in the help articles about every aspect of the site, we'd wind up with full documentation - which would quickly go out of date and be much harder to parse out important info.

Comment: So [meta-tag:status-declined] then?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd My initial inclination is to decline it, but I thought I'd allow anyone who feels strongly to try convincing me otherwise before I marked the question as such. :)

Comment: I can understand the rationale, however, I wonder that, if there is already a FAQ, why it is not linked to at least in the help section. After all, you are often enough refered to the FAQs or are encouraged to read the help section BEFORE you seriously start using a website, so it would feel natural to me, that there is at least a hint in the help section, escpecially if such a page already exists anyway and jsut needs a link to it.